# Would it be suitable and possible to migrate "How to get started learning Chinese?" (currently closed at Chinese.SE) here?

Tags: support, migration

I'm not 100% sure this is even possible, but at Chinese.SE there's the question [How to get started learning Chinese? [closed]](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/7053/how-to-get-started-learning-chinese).  Maybe if it were migrated here, it would be on-topic?

**Question**: Would it be suitable and possible to migrate "How to get started learning Chinese?" here?

I just thought I'd ask; it's a bit of a pity that a score-10 question is closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually find such questions very broad, since language learning encompasses so many things: various skills, types of learning methods, types of learning materials, knowledge of typologically similar languages, time available to the learner, etc. This is why I wrote up the meta question [How do I avoid asking questions that are too broad?](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/q/638/800)

For [that specific question](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/7053/12854), a good answer would first require that we know about more about the learner, especially what sort of language learning experience they already have (Why would getting started in Chinese be any different for them? Or is it their first foreign language? Advice can be tailored based on that.) and how much time they have available (Don't even bother if you have only two hours per week, I would say based on my own experience.)?

That specific question is too old to be migrated, but it can be made more specific and/or divided up into more specific questions to be asked here.